# Adding prepareForSegue into UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertaction

I would like to pass an array to another `ViewController` when pressing the "Next" button in the alertview.

```
userInformation += [userName, userGender, String(userAge), String(userHeight), String(userWeight)]

let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Confirmation", message: confirmationMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let confirmBtn : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!)-> Void in

    let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("toPerInfo"))! as UIViewController

    print(self.userInformation)

    self.showDetailViewController(vc, sender: self)

})

let cancelBtn : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelBtn)
    alert.addAction(confirmBtn)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and here is the `perpareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var destViewController: PersonalInformation = segue.destinationViewController as! PersonalInformation
        var arrayToSegue: [String] = self.userInformation
        destViewController.useInfo = arrayToSegue
    }
```

I would like to put the `perpareForSegue` into the "next" button.
How should I modify my code.. 
I couldn't find other similar questions...

Answer (score 0):

The method `prepareForSegue`is actually made to customize or pass data to the new view controller, as written in `UIViewController` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) :

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses override this method and use it to configure the new view controller prior to it being displayed. The segue object contains information about the transition, including references to both view controllers that are involved.

---

If you really want to, you can push manually the `PersonalInformation` view controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let destVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PersonalInformationId") as! PersonalInformation
var arrayToSegue: [String] = self.userInformation
destVC = arrayToSegue

// present or push, as you wish 
presentViewController(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: or is there any way i can pass data without segue ?

Comment: You can using manual push or present like my example. But you have to use it either manually (calling push or present methods), or using a segue.